# VideoView is not working and black screen

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I want to make a video view running at my started_activity background. But it fails to load.

The screen is black and if I navigate or push my page to another page 2 times, it will show app is not responding alert.

I follow this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPeDn18FrGY&t=210s

**started_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartedActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnToLoginPage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ActiviyStarted.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class StartedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView videoview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_started);

        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video_background);
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoview.start();

        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
        });

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToLoginPage);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(StartedActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                StartedActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code with video view

[image]

Code without video view

[image]

Video Path and error message
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        videoview.stopPlayback();
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoview.start();
    }
});
videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.start();
```

You can also set `setOnErrorListener` to check for the error:

```
videoview.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        //check error here
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to use this code to print the error but nothing show up `Log.d("VIDEOVIEWERROR:","WHAT: "+ what + " EXTRA: "+extra);`

Comment: I think it's correct. I uploaded the file path screenshot. u can check it.

Comment: @WanJern try with some other device, and move the code in `onResume` and try again.

Comment: I found that it's not the emulator problem. because the error message will appear when I deleted the video view code. so I updated my question.

Comment: Aww, I found the problem. I compressed my video file size 60MB to 5MB. and its work fine. so video file size cannot to big?

Comment: @WanJern I think it is not able to load.